# Is there any Java Console App Framwork without creating an own shell

Tags: java

is there any framework that supports building console apps in java?
I know about [Spring-Shell](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-shell) but that creates a shell that is not needed for my purpose.

For example i would like to create annotated Command-Classes like...

```
@Command(name="c", desc="Copies files from source directory to target directory.")
public class MyCopyCommand {

  @Argument(mandatory=true, desc="source directory")
  private String sourceDirectory;

  @Argument(mandatory=true, desc="target directory")
  private String targetDirectory;

  @Execute
  public void copy() {
     // copy files  
  }
}
```

And some Executor-Class should process the given program arguments and invoke the appropriate Command-Class.

Is there any Framwork like that? The best it would integrate with [Spring](http://spring.io/).

Comment: How about [JCurses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/)?

Comment: Or something like an [Ant Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)?

Comment: Hi Elliott, thanks for the two tips. JCurses as a windowing toolkit is not the right thing. Further i couldn't find a good documentation for this framework.

Comment: Sorry but ant is also not a solution. It doesn't act as a framework for my purpose.

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "own shell" or framework, [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) has abstractions for task scheduling. [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) provides a "Test Running" framework.

Comment: My app should run directly on the provided shell of the operating system without creating an own shell to execute commands. Maybe Framework is too much. Perhaps some Helper Classes would do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i've implemented it with Spring-Shell. Spring-Shell doesn't open a shell if the program is invoked with a command.

> ./myApp => opens shell
>
> ./myApp myCommand => doesn't open a shell

That suites for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

There is [Apache Felix Gogo](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-gogo.html) and [it is extensible](http://felix.apache.org/site/61-extending-the-console.html). The example even uses the same `@Command` annotation as in the OP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this is running/creating an own shell. My app should also work directly on windows shell (cmd) or e.g. unix bash without creating an own shell.